# How to edit a message in discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I would like to have my bot edit a message if it detects a keyword, i'm not sure how to edit the message though.

I've looked through the documentation but can't seem to figure it out. I'm using discord.py with python 3.6.

This is the code:

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if 'test' in message.content:
        await edit(message, "testtest")
```

This is the error:

```
  File "testthing.py", line 67, in on_message
    await edit(message, "test")
 NameError: name 'edit' is not defined
```

I would like the bot to edit a message to "testtest" if the message contains the word test, but i just get an error.

Comment: What version of discord.py are you using? `print(discord.__version__)`

Comment: Discord.py 1.0.0

Answer (score 25):

You can use the [`Message.edit`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.edit) coroutine.  The arguments must be passed as keyword arguments `content`, `embed`, or `delete_after`.  You may only edit messages that you have sent.

```
await message.edit(content="newcontent")
```

Comment: I tried it, but i just get this error:
        raise Forbidden(r, data)
    discord.errors.Forbidden: FORBIDDEN (status code: 403): Cannot edit a 
    message authored by another user

Comment: Although I have admin permissions on the bot.

Comment: @nijwons Actually, the docs for [`manage_messages`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Permissions.manage_messages) lead me to believe that you cannot edit another users message.

Comment: Oh, is that so? Is it the same for nicknames as i get the same error with that.

Comment: @nijwons There is a permission for that: [`manage_nicknames`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Permissions.manage_nicknames).  Make sure your bot has that, and check if it is a role hierarchy issue.  Your bot may not be able to edit users whose highest role is higher than the highest role of the bot.

Comment: Should we store the `message` object which is created from `await self.channel.send(msg)` ?

Answer (score 10):

Here's a solution that worked for me.

```
@client.command()
async def test(ctx):
  message = await ctx.send("hello")
  await asyncio.sleep(1)
  await message.edit(content="newcontent")
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you do this:

```
from discord import edit
```

or this:

```
from discord import *
```

before using message.edit function?

If you did it, maybe the problem is with your discord.py version.
Try this:

```
print(discord.__version__)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to update responses in discord.py you have to use:

```
@tree.command(name = 'foobar', description = 'Send the word foo and update it to say bar')
async def self(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    await interaction.response.send_message(f'foo', ephemeral = True)
    time.sleep(1)
    await interaction.edit_original_response(content=f'bar')
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign the original message to a variable. Reference the variable with `.edit(content='content')`.

(You need "`content=`" in there).

```py
@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
    msg = await ctx.send('test')
    await msg.edit(content='this message has been edited')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.content == 'test':
    messages=await message.channel.send("CONTENT")
    await asyncio.sleep(INT)
    await messages.edit(content="NEW CONTENT")
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try to add `def` to your code like this:

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if 'test' in message.content:
        await edit(message, "edited !")
```

Answer (score -1):

This is what I did:

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.content == 'test':
    await message.channel.send('Hello World!')
    await message.edit(content='testtest')
```

I don't know if this will work for you, but try and see.