# Typewriter effect in discord.py (i used google translate to ask this question, sry for any mistakes)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, typewriter

```
async def type(ctx):
words = "Hello"
for x in words:
    await ctx.send(x)
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

Output:

```
H
e
l
l
o
```

They are not displayed in one line.
What must I do to fix this problem?

Comment: What is the problem exactly?

Comment: They are not displayed in one line

Comment: What is a "typewriter effect" in this context?

Comment: program which reads characters from a string and prints each character after some delay so its look like typing effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending a new message for every iteration of your loop, use [Message.edit](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=edit#discord.Message.edit) instead.  Also, you need to use [asyncio.sleep](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.sleep) in place of `time.sleep` in async functions.

So something like:

```
message = None
for i in range(len(words)):
    if not message:
        message = await ctx.send(words[:i+1])
        continue

    await message.edit(content=words[:i+1])
    await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
```

Note that discord will likely rate limit you if you do this with longer messages.

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible by sending messages, you need to edit them.

Example of [editing your message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55711572/how-to-edit-a-message-in-discord-py). The only modification needed for your code, is to first send 'H' as a regular message. Then edit that message, appending a new character at a time.

Comment: How do you even know what's being asked?

Comment: If OP is trying to write one character at a time in a horizontal line, what's stopping them from editing their bot's Discord message and adding the new character to the end each time?

Comment: I read the code, the question and the tags. He is basically asking to make the bots message animated. He can do this by modifying his message one letter at a time

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55711572/how-to-edit-a-message-in-discord-py) is a thread about how to edit messages that have been sent.

Comment: Should be good now, might add an example if the question is not resolved.

Comment: @JacksonTaylor I think it makes sense. I will try it. Thx for help