# Edit message in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I want my bot to send a message and process it again after a certain period of time
What I've already tried:

```
@client.command()
async def test(ctx):
    await ctx.send ('content')
    await asyncio.sleep(3)
    await message.edit(content="newcontent")
```

The error message:

```
AttributeError: module 'discord.message' has no attribute 'edit'
```

I use the following:

- Python version: 3.7.4
- discord.py version 1.6.0

Comment: Where did you define the `message` variable?

Comment: This would probably help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/62191673/5842628

Comment: Can you share a [mre] that actually includes where and how you defined `message`?

Answer (score 3):

You would have to define `message` first.

```py
@client.command()
async def test(ctx):
    message = await ctx.send("content")
    await asyncio.sleep(3)
    await message.edit(content="newcontent")
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a few errors in your code. One: there is a space between your `ctx.send` and your message `('content')`. Your current code:

```py
await ctx.send ('content')
```

Should be changed to:

```py
await ctx.send('content')
```

The above doesn't need to be changed, although it is suggested. Also, make sure to define `message`:

```py
message = await ctx.send('content')
```

Then you can `edit` the message:

```py
await message.edit('new_content')
```

Comment: `message.edit` is a coroutine, it should be awaited

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I was in a rush at the moment and forgot to add the `await` keyword to the beginning of the coroutine.

Comment: In Python, whitespace between the function name and the parentheses does not affect running the function. While putting unnecessary whitespace between the function name and the parentheses is discouraged, it does not raise an error.