# Is it possible to create a constantly updating progress bar for commands? [Discord.py]

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, progress-bar

I have a particularly large and resource-intensive command that takes a while to actually output anything. I was wondering if it were possible to create an ASCII progress bar that is constantly edited by the bot to indicate progress, perhaps similar to this:[image]

Could this be possible, and how?

Answer (score 1):

You can call [`.edit()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Message.edit) on a message to change its contents.

```
progress_bar = await some_channel.send('=>..')
# after some things finish
await progress_bar.edit(content = '==>.')
# after some more things finish
await progress_bar.edit(content = '===>')
```

Calling `.send()` will return a `message` object that can be manipulated with any of the [message methods](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#message).

[relevant stack overflow post about editing message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55711572/how-to-edit-a-message-in-discord-py).